# pandas - plotting x-axis manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I feel like this should be simple, but after a couple hours, I cannot get the desired result on a plot I am making.  I have tried many xticks in the plot call, using set_xticklabels, and seem to make things worse.  I want all the values to show on the x-axis, instead of the abbreviated result I am getting.

DataFrame:

[image]

Result:
[image]

I would like to see all the labels on the x axis - can / how can this be accomplished?

Comment: look at the `xticks` argument. If you would provide your input data as text we could use it for developing a __working__ solution...

Comment: You can pass an array for the `xticks` arg such as `df.plot(xticks=df.index)` but this may look a bit cramped

Comment: @EdChum I tried as you mentioned.  It works, but only if the index is list of integers.  I get ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 9 PM when trying to use my current index of strings.

Comment: you can use `df.index.tolist()`

Comment: If you prefix your code with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and then `plt.xticks(range(len(df.index)), df.index)
plt.show()` it should fill your xticks with the desired labels